# How do I use a method to return / calculate an attribute?

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

I want to do something like:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.X_train = self.split_scale_data(X,y)[0]
        self.X_test = self.split_scale_data(X,y)[1]

    def split_scale_data(self, X, y):
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
        scaler = MinMaxScaler()
        X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
        X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
        return self.X_train, self.X_test
```

But I can't get this to work, and I can't find any examples online where someone uses a method to calculate an attribute. I get Attribute Error: 'Model' object has no attribute 'X_train'. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean you can't get that to work? Are you getting an error? If so can you please paste the full traceback?

Comment: I get 'Model' object has no attribute 'X_train' @CoryKramer

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: `self.X_train` doesn't exist until after `self.split_scale_data()` returns from its call in `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `split_scale_data` returns the following

```
return self.X_train, self.X_test
```

but it should return the local variables from that method

```
return X_train, X_test
```

By the way you can also modify your `__init__` method to use this method as

```
self.X_train, self.X_test = self.split_scale_data(X,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning attributes which are not defined

```
return self.X_train, self.X_test
```

and here the error. You should change it to

```
return X_train, X_test
```

However, for your use case it might be worth to use a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) and keep the `__init__` simple.

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, X, y, X_train, X_test):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.X_test = X_test

    @classmethod
    def from_data(cls, X, y):
       ...
       return cls(X, y, X_train, X_test)
```